# Get pair-wise single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some data in a MS SQL Server database. Sample data is:

| Sl | ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 112 |
| 2 | 112 | 111 |
| 3 | 113 | 114 |
| 4 | 114 | 113 |
| 5 | 115 | 116 |
| 6 | 116 | 115 |

Now I need result like.

| ColumnA | ColumnA |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 112 |
| 113 | 114 |
| 115 | 116 |

Notice here:

In Sl 1 number Column A = Sl 2 Column B
and Sl 1 number Column B = Sl 2 Column A

Same as:

In Sl 3 number Column A = Sl 4 Column B
and Sl 3 number Column B = Sl 4 Column A

Comment: Hi !   I do understand the firste examples but the third line is unclear to me as there are NO  conditions met like      SI(5) (A)  ==   SI(6) (B) &&  SI(5) (B)  ==   SI(6) (A)   ???  is this a bug in your data or is the explanation missing something?

Comment: Ok it was a data bug. I saw you fixed it.   Second question : The second table has two rows with ColumnA  - shouldn't this be ColumnB?

Comment: If every row is paired with the next in an odd/even fashion, you can just do `where si % 2 = 0`

Comment: is     (A) 111   (B) 112 the same as (A) 112   (B) 111    and you simply want to remove the duplicates??  - - then you have a data normalization problem..

Comment: Sl will not be in a sequence.

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig yes, i want to Remove duplicates

Comment: Then I would  1.)  care of this problem already before - At the time of insertion. hen inserting values. Always insert the lower value in field A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `CASE` expressions to find the least/greatest value in each record:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN ColumnA < ColumnB  THEN ColumnA ELSE ColumnB END AS ColumnA,
    CASE WHEN ColumnA >= ColumnB THEN ColumnA ELSE ColumnB END AS ColumnB
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY 1;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Note that in certain other databases (such as MySQL and Postgres), there are formal `LEAST` and `GREATEST` functions, which can simplify and eliminate the need for the bulky `CASE` expressions used above.

Comment: @AminurRahman ??? not sure what this comment is supposed to mean.  Did you intend to put it under the question perhaps?

Comment: BTW: Are you aware that the OP ants to deduplicate a one to many relationship saved in one table?

Answer (score 0):

If you have reversed pairs for all rows, then you can simply use:

```
select columnA, columnB
from t
where columnA < columnB;
```

If you don't always have a matching "reversed" row, then you can enhance this with `not exists`:

```
select t.columnA, t.columnB
from t
where t.columnA < t.columnB or
      not exists (select 1 
                  from t t2 
                  where t2.columnA = t.columnB and
                        t2.columnB = t.columnA
                 );
```

Both of these should perform better than aggregation or `select distinct`, under most circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The OP tells us in a comment, that in fact he only wants to deduplicate the table.

So I am pretty sure that this problem asked above only the symptom of an underlying problem i would suggest a completely different approach.

To fix this I would

1.)  quick fix:  care of this problem already before - At the time of insertion put the lower value into field A. Then you will not have this kind of duplicates.  OR BETTER: use a second column   with  fields  id  (AI) and SI and Value.  for one specfic SID you then have two records - one with 111 and one with 112.

2.)  THE PROFESSIOBNAL WAY - with correct normalization:
Create TWO TABLES

table 1

```
SI  and all other fields
```

table 2

```
id (AI) |  SI (not UNIQUE) | value
```

for each value SI in table 1 you have n (2 for example but can be n)  records in table 2

e.g. for SID you would have  2 records with

id     SID    value
{id}    3     113
{id}    3     114

This helps you a lot with various SQl queries as you have a better structure. And you can have AS many values per SID (0-n) as you like without having to change the table structure each time to accomondate column  AAZ ;-)